# Squarespace Developer Mode adding files

Tags: javascript, html, squarespace

I am in developer mode in the .region file trying to add a background video with the video tag. I put the mp4 file into the template folder and I have been trying to access it through src="video.mp4" and display the video. It doesn't display the video and I am not sure why I can't grab it. When i change the source to any http// video online it works so its not the code. It only doesn't display the video when I try grabbing it from the local folder. Any leads or help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files that are directly located in the `/template` folder are not intended to be accessible via http. Instead, put the file within `/template/assets` and then reference the file as `/assets/video.mp4`.

If that doesn't help, ensure that the file is even accessible via http by entering `http://yoursite.squarespace.com/assets/video.mp4` in the address bar (using your site's correct URL). If you can access the video file, then it will work as a `src` attribute of a video element. If you cannot access it, then something else is going on: either you haven't uploaded the file or the file name is incorrect.

Another tip: if using the full URL for a file (as opposed to the relative URL), try using `https` for the protocol in place of `http`. The correct protocol depends on your site's settings, of course, and whether you are using your built-in or custom domain.

If using the local development server via Node.js (as opposed to the live server, that is, your actual Squarespace site), try pushing/uploading the files to the live server on Squarespace (via Git or SFTP) and then retesting locally. I've found that sometimes this may be required due to caching in the local environment. This will also reveal whether the file you are uploading is too large ([the documentation](https://developers.squarespace.com/template-overview) does claim a 1MB limit which may be true, though it may be as large as 5MB or 20MB if the docs are out of date; I cannot recall whether this has changed).

If the file is too large for the `/assets` folder, then your only other option besides hosting it via a different service entirely is to use the [file storage via the Squarespace Config UI](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files), which allows up to 20MB, and referencing your video via that path. You'd have to get the video down to 20MB by shortening, scaling or further compressing it.

If hosting the file via a different service, Cloudinary may be worth considering; a free account may allow [up to a 100MB video file](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520592-Do-you-have-a-file-size-limit-) and enough bandwidth (assuming your website's traffic is relatively low).

Comment: I meant I accessed a file that was online with http fine. then tried accesing local with normal call. I put the video in assets folder after template and called the video your way and still nothing. 
<video autoplay loop id="v0" muted  autoplay>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="/assets/video.mp4"></source>
    </video>

Comment: Yeah I tried http//mylocalserver/assets/video.mp4 with no luck. So it seems your last paragraph might be the case where I probably have to upload the mp4 file. So I tried pushing with git after putting it in my folder then realized it was too big as I believe I max file size to push is 1mb. So is this the only way to get the video to upload? or is there a way to get this 50mb file to live server somehow? maybe shrinking it? I'm not sure.

Comment: See updated answer with additional options, @DaveValles.

Comment: Thank you! Things are a lot more clear now and I understand my options better!